# Logstash with IRC is not seem to be working

Tags: logstash, logstash-configuration

I am trying to grab messages from IRC with Logstash, but I am not getting anything. Here is my config file:

```
input {
        irc {
                channels => ["#logstash"]
                host     => "irc://irc.freenode.net"
                user     => "abcde"
        }  
}

filter {

}

output {
        stdout {}
}
```

Is there something I am missing?

Here is the documentation on that plugin for Logstash:

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-inputs-irc.html

I am using Logstash 1.5.5.